# Powershell code to download all subfolder of Blob content to local into single folder

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-blob-storage

Explanation of the scenario - Previously I was trying to do activity of downloading the blob content to the local using PS code with respect to the specific blob path folder and Date parameterization.Now that's is working fine. But there is change needed as below - Ideas are welcome surely so that i can boost on it. 
I've multiple sub folders inside the blob path assume - A/B/C, C is having folder1, folder2 etc....
How do I get all in one single folder using PS code. And now, within C that subfolders having multiple blob content is getting download as one-one folder assume -00,01,02 like whats is available in blob.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it readable at least.

Comment: Done, ... the above thing has only question.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to download all files from sub folders in a single folder on your local computer. Correct?

Comment: Yes, your are correct you can make it like this - all files available in a subfolders that multiple subfolders to be available as a single folder currently its getting as - like this format as from the blob structure. A/B/C is blob c had dates folder and inside dates it has 01,02.... in Local also its getting static till A/B...Gets the current date-1 using PS code then inside that its having 10-20 folders which has blob contents..

Comment: Working script is here till now- $path = "A/B"
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix $path$date -Context $storage_account  
foreach($blob in $blobs) {  
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path  
    Get-AzStorageBlobContent -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path -Context $storage_account  
}

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Instead edit your question and include it there. Also, please make sure that code is formatted properly (https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Sure thanks for the response, will take it up on not adding the code on comments as well the formatting to be taken care. I will try reading the link for formatting as well shared to me. As of now for the above post - am doing it will child item but I'm not sure how it will work becoz its blob path to local

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 0327:**

The code below will download each file into each folder:

```
$container_name="test10"
$destination_path="d:\ccc"

$user="xxx"
$pwd = "xxxxxx"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $user -StorageAccountKey $pwd

$path = "A/B" 
#$date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$date="2020-03-24"

$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix "$path/$date" -Context $context

$i=0
foreach($blob in $blobs )
{

$blobName = $blob.Name -split "/" | select -Last 1
Write-Output "downloading blob $blobName"

$finalDirectory = New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path "$($destination_path)\$i"

$finalPath = "$($finalDirectory)\$($blobName)"
$blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToFile($finalPath,[System.IO.FileMode]::CreateNew)
$i=$i+1
}

Write-Output "***completed downloading***"
```

---

**Original answer:**

If you're using `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` cmdlet to download blobs, then there is no way to change the structure.

But you can use `$blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToFile` method of the `$blob object`, which can meet your requirement:

sample code(Tested by myself, all the blobs including the ones within subfolders are downloaded into one single folder locally):

```
$container_name="test10"
$destination_path="d:\ccc"

$user="storage_account_name"
$pwd = "storage_account_key"
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $user -StorageAccountKey $pwd    

$path = "A/B" 
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

$blobs = Get-AzStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Prefix "$path/$date" -Context $context

foreach($blob in $blobs )
{

#get the name by removing the directory/folder name of a blob
$blobName = $blob.Name -split "/" | select -Last 1
Write-Output "downloading blob $blobName"

$finalPath = "$($destination_path)\$($blobName)"
$blob.ICloudBlob.DownloadToFile($finalPath,[System.IO.FileMode]::CreateNew)

}

Write-Output "***completed downloading***"
```

Please let me know if you still have more issues.

Comment: Just saw your code now, Will test end to end on my end and understand if that works with my requirement if any issues I will reach you back here. Thanks for this great work..!!

Comment: @anirudhbragadeesan, yeah, and please let me know if there are some issues.

Comment: Can you quickly make the substitutes of what has to be replaced where in the above code so that i can check it once. Thanks

Comment: @anirudhbragadeesan, just replace the value of the $container_name / $destination_path / $user / $pwd

Comment: tried doing that now, but no download happens or such execution as expected can we have a quick sync in call.

Comment: hi @anirudhbragadeesan, could you please add your code in your post? as well can you please add a screenshot of your blob storage in azure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210283/discussion-between-ivan-yang-and-anirudh-bragadeesan).

Comment: Yep sure thats great thanks, Let me attend one meeting and come back in short while at around - 3.30 PM IST hope that suits your end..!!!

Comment: Location: sourcefiles / folder1 / folder2 / folder3    Folder 3 has subfolders like 01,02...and each subfolder has 100 files, which needs to be under one folder..